# Business multi-screen recorder

Tags: windows-7, screen-recording

I'm looking for a solution which can record a video of 6 screens running from 2 video cards on the same PC.

The purpose is for a control station, so it needs to startup when the PC starts and the user be unable to cancel the recording or mess with the previously recorded files.

So far I've come across [Screen Anytime](http://www.screen-record.com/screen_anytime.htm) which looks OK, however it causes the mouse to flicker while it's recording which is very annoying. It's also pretty expensive, but it's not out of my price range since it's for business use.

Other software I've looked at needs to be triggered by the user or can be stopped easily, or its geared towards call centres which is not what I'm after.

Comment: What operating system?  Free or paid?  It sounds like Windows and paid is okay, but please clarify and tag appropriately.

Comment: windows 7, paid is ok with a budget of about $1000.